# Recursively check for atoms in a list

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I am attempting to write a small recursive program that tests a list and returns **t** if every element is an atom.  The problem I am having is that when the function receives an empty list, it returns **t** instead of the desired result of **nil**.  I cannot come up with a way to have it return **nil** for an initially empty list and still function properly in a recursive manner.

```
(defun only-atoms (in)
  (if (null in)
    t
    (and (atom (first in)) (only-atoms (cdr in)) )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can be implemented without recursion using e.g. `every`, as in:

```
(defun only-atoms (list)
  (and list (every #'atom list)))
```

When it comes to your stated problem that the function returns `T` instead of the desired result of `NIL` when the function is called with an empty list:

1. Your recursive implementation explicitly returns `T` if `(null in)` is true, which explains your finding. Simply change it to the desired value `NIL`. Consider changing the `if` construct to `and`.
2. Only make the recursive call when the list has more than one item. A well placed test for `(rest in)` will do. Provide a true value instead of making the recursive call if the list is at its last item.
3. Carefully locate the `only-atoms` call to ensure that the function can be tail-recursive.

For example:

```
    (defun only-atoms (list)
      (and list
          (atom (first list))
          (or (null (rest list))
              (only-atoms (rest list)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use COND, which allows you to test for several cases:

- empty list -> nil
- one element list -> atom? ; hint: don't use LENGTH
- else -> atom? for first element and recursive call for rest elements

Answer (score 1):

The empty list *does* fulfill the condition that every element is an atom!  Your requirement that it should contain at least one element is an *additional* requirement.

The simplest way to express "every element of the list is an atom" is `(every #'atom list)`.  You can combine it with your additional requirement with `and`.

If you insist on doing it recursively in SICP-style, separate your requirements:

```
(defun not-empty-and-all-atoms (list)
  (and list
       (all-atoms list)))

(defun all-atoms (list)
  (if (endp list)
      t
      (and (atom (first list))
           (all-atoms (rest list)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works correctly:

```
(defun lat-p (lst)
           (labels ((lat-p* (lst) 
                      (cond
                       ((null lst) t)
                       ((atom (car lst)) (lat-p* (cdr lst)))
                       (t nil))))
             (if lst
                 (lat-p* lst)
                 nil)))
```

However a much more elegant solution(with no recursion) would be:

```
(defun lat-p (lst)
           (and lst (every #'atom lst)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split your function in two, and provide the initial `nil` screening before you enter recursion. The following code is one way to do so (I tried to keep it as close to provided code as possible):

```
(defun only-atoms (in)
  (defun only-atoms-iter (in)
    (if (null in)
        t
      (and (atom (first in)) (only-atoms-iter (cdr in)))))

  (unless (null in)
      (only-atoms-iter in)))
```

This is also a good opportunity to make your function tail recursive:

```
(defun only-atoms (in)
  (defun only-atoms-iter (in state)
    (if (null in)
        state
      (only-atoms-iter (cdr in) (and state (atom (first in))))))

  (unless (null in)
      (only-atoms-iter in t)))
```

Comment: Nested DEFUNs are wrong. For local functions use FLET or Labels. No, avoid tailrecursion unless you are knowing what you are doing and/or you are programming with Scheme.

Comment: I knew I should have added a comment about me not being too familiar with CL. I've mainly worked with Scheme, and commented for that. My bad. :) However, I don't think this invalidates the main answer: check first, recurse later.

Comment: Scheme allows nested DEFINEs, in Lisp nested DEFUNS are a mistake and won't do what you think they do.